# C# how to record general audio from output device ( speaker ) with NAudio API

Tags: c#, audio-recording, naudio, speaker

I'm trying to record the Speaker Output to detect volume and BPM from any playing music with C# and NAudio API.

The problem is, i don't know how to do that :/

i have a sample code from http://opensebj.blogspot.de/2009/04/naudio-tutorial-5-recording-audio.html where they record simple input with less code...

```
waveInStream = new WaveIn(44100,2);
```

what does the "44100, 2" means ? does that targets the device to record from ???

how can i target speaker output ?

does anyone can help me out ? or even with another API ?

thx

Comment: The 44100 means "samples per second" - it's the same as ordinary cd's - often shortened to 44.1 The 2 I'm not 100% sure but it could mean stereo ie 2 channels not mono being 1.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you're probably looking for is the `WasapiLoopbackCapture` class, which allows you to record all the sound your computer is producing. **NOTE**: This works in Windows Vista/7 only!

To start recording, do this:

```
waveIn = new WasapiLoopbackCapture();
waveIn.DataAvailable += InputBufferToFileCallback;    
waveIn.StartRecording();
```

Then, every time the recording buffer is full, the `InputBufferToFileCallback` function will be called:

```
public void InputBufferToFileCallback(object sender, WaveInEventArgs e)
{
  // The recorder bytes can be found in e.Buffer
  // The number of bytes recorded can be found in e.BytesRecorded
  // Process the audio data any way you wish...
}
```

I think you've been put on the wrong track by the tutorial you linked, because in the current release of NAudio I don't see the `new WaveIn(44100,2);` constructor. NAudio probably has been modified since the tutorial was first written.

As a final note, the numbers 44100 and 2 denote the sample rate and the number of channels respectively.

Comment: thank you. I'll try that soon. but for now it seems right for me ^^

Comment: how can i get the value of the data , lets say the volume of the deeper sounds, maybe the 32 & 64 hz area ? i want to make a light flicker to the beat... i dont have any experience in sudio programming. how can i handle the audio data in real time ?

Comment: I don't know the exact answer to that one, but you might want to do the following:

1. Add a break point just after you start recording and look at the waveIn variable to see what the audio properties are (like sample rate, number of bits, channels etc.)
2. Read up on PCM (Pulse-code Modulation), which is the format in which the audio is encoded (also known WAV, Wikipedia might be a good start)
3. Take a careful look at the demos included with Naudio and search or ask for more info there. (http://naudio.codeplex.com/discussions)

Comment: I wish I could buy you a beer. Loopback is exactly what I needed!

Comment: what is the windows 8.1 equivalent?

Answer (score 0):

As said in the accepted answer, the code on the tutorial you are following is from an older version of NAudio, in that version the sample rate and channel count needed to be passed as parameters to `WaveIn` constructor.

As the answer suggest you to use the `WasapiLoopbackCapture`, maybe this can complement it.

The newer implementations of NAudio doesn't takes the sample rate (`44100`) and number of channels (`2`) as parameters for `WaveIn` constructor. You can simply call the `WaveIn` constructor without parameters:

```
waveInStream = new WaveIn();
```