# How do I record audio from speakers?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, naudio

```
Imports NAudio
Imports System.IO
Imports NAudio.Utils

Public Class Form1
    Private waveSource As Wave.WaveIn = Nothing
    Private waveFile As Wave.WaveFileWriter = Nothing
    Private waveFileWriter As Wave.WaveFileWriter
    Dim ms As MemoryStream

    Private Sub waveSource_DataAvailable(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Wave.WaveInEventArgs)
        waveFileWriter.Write(e.Buffer, 0, e.BytesRecorded)
        waveFileWriter.Flush()
    End Sub

    Private Sub waveSource_RecordingStopped(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Wave.StoppedEventArgs)
        Dim fs As FileStream = File.Create(Environment.CurrentDirectory & "\test.wav")
        ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)
        ms.CopyTo(fs)
    End Sub

    Private Sub startBTN_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles startBTN.Click
        ms = New MemoryStream()

        waveFileWriter = New Wave.WaveFileWriter(New IgnoreDisposeStream(ms), waveSource.WaveFormat)
        waveSource.StartRecording()
    End Sub

    Private Sub stopBTN_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles stopBTN.Click
        waveSource.StopRecording()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        waveSource = New Wave.WaveIn

        AddHandler waveSource.DataAvailable, AddressOf waveSource_DataAvailable
        AddHandler waveSource.RecordingStopped, AddressOf waveSource_RecordingStopped
    End Sub
End Class
```

Translating the code from the following post, this throws "Bad Device ID" exception.

[Naudio Recording and playing audio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27532663/naudio-recording-and-playing-audio)

I don't have any recording devices (or WaveIn). Is that why?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. NAudio is opensource. You can debug it and discover this for yourself.

Investigate WASAPI capture. I don't know whether that will work, but it's a next step.

Answer (score 1):

[C# how to record general audio from output device ( speaker ) with NAudio API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11828437/c-sharp-how-to-record-general-audio-from-output-device-speaker-with-naudio-a)

```
    Private waveSource As Wave.WasapiLoopbackCapture = Nothing
```

Changing `Wave.WaveIn` to `Wave.WasapiLoopbackCapture` solved my issue. Of course, there's still a problem with my code (be aware). Hitting stop stops the capture but doesn't write the file. It is only until you force exit the application does the .wav save to disk. I can figure that out on my own.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in `Private Sub waveSource_RecordingStopped` to see the `.wav` without closing application:

```
fs.Dispose()
```